# How to write a Test method

Tags: apex, unit-test

Someone plz help me how to write test method for below method

```
public static Integer getFolderIndex(String frup_folderName, String recordName){
   Integer  folderIndex = 0;

   if ( !frup_folderName.equalsignorecase(recordName)) {
        folderIndex = integer.valueof(frup_folderName.substringAfter(recordName+'_'));
   }
   system.debug('folder index'+folderIndex);
   return folderIndex;
}
```

What I have written

```
static testMethod void  getFolderIndex(){ 
   Integer  folderIndex = 0;
   Integer objectLabel2 = UtilityClass.getFolderIndex('Folder213','Recoed1');
}
```

I am getting following error

> System.TypeException: Invalid integer:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this line of code

```
folderIndex = integer.valueof(frup_folderName.substringAfter(recordName+'_'));
```

and you are passing in the values 'Folder213' and 'Recoed1'

so what will be the result of frup_folderName.substringAfter(recordName+'_') ?

It will look for "Recoed1_" within the string "Folder213" and return the text after that. Since the search string doesn't exist within the initial string, it will return blank which cannot be evaluated to an Integer, hence your problem.

You might want to break this down to show the problem better

```
String temp = frup_folderName.substringAfter(recordName+'_');
System.debug(temp);
if (temp.isNumeric()) {
   folderIndex = integer.valueof(temp);
} else {
   // handle your error
}
```

Your test might be intended to look something like this:

```
Integer objectLabel2 = UtilityClass.getFolderIndex('MyPrefix_213','MyPrefix');
```

Comment: Oh!! yeah you are correct. Silly me. Thank you for your help :)